# How do I ensure the MAPI client receives focus when I launch it?

Tags: delphi, winapi, mapi

I've got a function that launches a user's default e-mail program via MAPI. The mail program usually launches on top of my app, but sometimes it doesn't; sometimes my application remains on top of the desktop display. Is there any way to assure the user's e-mail program will launch on top of the desktop, not buried behind other open applications?

Comment: How do you launch it? `ShellExecute` with a `mailto:` argument? What flag do you use? `SW_SHOWNORMAL`?

Comment: I'm actually using the JCL library's simple MAPI mail class, simply calling its Send function.

Comment: could you minimize the calling app windows so it can not hide the mail client?

Comment: Which Delphi version? I seem to recall that older Delphi versions have Z-ordering issues.

Comment: @Al C - If this is 'TJclEmail', have you tried setting its 'ParentWnd' property?

Answer (score -1):

you need to find the window wich you want to be on top using findwindow api an then call setforegroundwindow api

Comment: `SetForegroundWindow` can only be called in special circumstances. And your calling program might not fulfill those. In particular it can call SetForegroundWindow if it is the active process itself, but usually can't if a third application has focus. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Wouldn't my program need to know the title/caption on a user's (default MAPI) e-mail client to be able to do this?

Comment: @codeinchaos : it can be easily fixed by calling createremotethread and executing setforegroundwindow api inside the process 
@Al C of course but that is easy to find

Comment: Yes, @AlC, you will need to know the class name and title of the window that the MAPI program creates, which makes this answer a non-starter.

Comment: I have written my own mail client, with the caption "#$%@#$%". How can Al C's app can guess that?

Comment: @Torbins - So do you mean that the question essentially is *"I want to bring a window to front but I've got no idea which one"* ?

Comment: There are some programming problems which don't have perfect solution. But FindWindow+SetForegroundWindow in my opinion isn't even good one.

Comment: @Sertac: It doesn't seem very easy to me. There is no `GetWindow(hWnd, GW_LAST_OPENED_MAIL_CLIENT_WINDOW)`.

Comment: every window has a class and if you execute the code remotley it will work 100% since anybody didn't give a better answer i think i am right no??

Comment: @Andreas - LOL, true... But then that means in its current form the question itself deserves as much down-voting as opc0de's answer... AAMOF I can think of no other way: keep a list of class names for widely used mail clients, get the default mail client from the registry, if you have a match search for the window, if not let it go. Anyway, as Torbins said maybe this is no good..

Comment: It may not be perfect, but for now I decided to try hiding the application at the beginning of the function (with the ShowWindow procedure) and then restoring it to its previous state at the end of the function. ... My thanks to all of you who responded!

Comment: @AlC - If you're not content with your resolution maybe you could re-tag the question with 'windows' & 'winapi' to see if sth. comes up from non-delphi guys.

Comment: Yours being the only answer (or, rather, the first answer) doesn't make it right, @Opc0de. That's called a *false dilemma*. And just because every window has a class doesn't mean you'll know what that class is so that you can search for it with `FindWindow`, and neither does it mean that the class will uniquely identify the window you need. Running remotely has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

I think ShellExecute with SW_SHOWNORMAL or SW_SHOW flag is the best solution you can do. In combination with mailto: argument it will be something like that:

```
ShellExecute(Self.Handle, nil, '"mailto:somebody@example.com?subject=This is ' +
  'the subject&body=The message''s first paragraph.%0ASecond paragraph.%0AThird ' +
  'Paragraph."', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Of course this method can be used only for creating simple messages.

Comment: There's no such thing in `MAPISendMail`.

Comment: I meant mailto: argument, as Andreas Rejbrand already mentioned. It will be enough if Al C only needs simple messages.